# Laravel Validation - Array fields, only one of two allowed but neither is required

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using Laravel Form Request Validation to validate an array of objects, within each object we have two keys `neverExpires` and `numberOfBillingCycles`.  Neither of these two keys are required, but if both have a value validation should fail as I only want to accept one or the other.

```
"addOns": {
    "add": [
        {
            "inheritedFromId": "EMEX1",
            "neverExpires": "false",
            "numberOfBillingCycles": "10"   
        },
        {
            "inheritedFromId": "EX1",
            "neverExpires": "true"
        },
        {
            "inheritedFromId": "EX2"
        }
    ]
},
```

So, in the first instance, because both `neverExpires` and `numberOfBillingCycles` have values it should fail validation.  The second and third instances should pass as it only contains `neverExpires` or doesn't contain either.

I've tried creating a custom validator and passing in the two fields as parameters eg.`addOns.add.*.neverExpires` and `addOns.add.*.numberOfBillingCycles` but the problem is the parameter index is not set and I can't seem to find the array index within the custom rule to enable me to check the right array object values.

Hope this makes sense? Cheers in advance.

Comment: can you show us your store request file?

Comment: @JoseSilva I've torn it down now as couldn't get it to work at all sorry.  I've tried all the `require_without`, `require_if` etc and they don't appear to allow me to only ensure one or the other is completed or allow none of them to be completed.  I only want it to fail validation if both are present and have value.

Comment: did you tried after validation? function withValidator() ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @JoseSilva thanks for taking the time to reply but I went with Ross's solution as it did what I needed.

Comment: @JoseSilva you got me thinking about "after validation" and have since played with it some more and I've implemented a solution using both methods just to see how they work.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @PhilRowley i think is to late to post an awnser at this time. Glad to helped you. Maybe you must up vote my comment to help other ppl in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're using **>=** Laravel 5.5 you could validate the item in the `add` array rather than the individual attributes:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'addOns.add.*' => [
            function ($attr, $value, $fail) {
                if (array_has($value, ['inheritedFromId', 'numberOfBillingCycles'])) {
                    $fail('You can not have both');
                }
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Sorted!  This worked perfectly, thanks!  I wrote this method into its own custom rule but couldn't of done it without your help.